# Writing Files in HDFS- Using TextIO API vs Java - BufferedWriter(new FileWriter())

Tags: apache-beam

We have a requirement that we need to create files for each and every Employee ID. We used the groupbyKey feature and able to create the data structure.
< ID, Iterable < Employee Objects > > where we converted Iterable < Employee > to List.
Then we created a folder and a file for the Employee ID.
So in < EmployeeID, List < Employee > > object, for each and every row we loop and using BufferedWriter we write data into the file. IS it good enough or we need to use TextIO framework to do the same thing. The question is whether we will get drastic performance improvements using TextIO when compared to BufferedWriter to write data in files each and every row.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is surprisingly difficult to write files in a way that produces well-defined results and no data loss or duplication in case of failures. You can get a glimpse of this complexity by looking at the implementation of the `WriteFiles` transform, used by `TextIO` under the hood. So `TextIO` handles this complexity for you, and I strongly recommend using it, if you can - rather than using hand-crafted code. You probably want the `write().to(DynamicDestinations)` version.

If you're doing something that `TextIO` definitely can not do, I still recommend looking at the implementation of `WriteFiles` to get an understanding of what else needs to be done to make sure your code is resilient against failures.